# Why function $f(x)=a^x$ is not defined for negative 'a'

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why function $f(x)=a^x$ is not defined for negative 'a'

in class math teacher was explaining graphs about case when a is less than 1 and when a is greater than 1. But he said f is not defined for negative values of a. May i know why this is so?

Thanks

Comment: since for example $$(-2)^{\sqrt{2}}$$ makes no sence for $x$ in reals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because some **non-integer** values of $x$ would yield **non-real** values of $f(x)$.

For example, if $a=-1$, then $x=\frac12$ would yield $f(x)=(-1)^{\frac12}=\sqrt[2]{-1}$.